Multiple solidify modifiers influencing each other when they shouldn't
I noticed while I was modeling an object with two solidify modifiers(to give different thicknesses to different parts) that the area under the influence of the second modifier was behaving strangely. The modifier was adding extra geometry even though it's only a simply solidify mod(the subdivision mod was off)

(with mod on)

(with mod off)
I figured out that the first solidify mod in the stack would work fine while any subsequent ones would break when I twiddled with the order

(now the mod works when it comes first)
Each solidify mod is paired to a different vertex group with zero overlap or fuzziness so they shouldn't affect each other
I made a brand new project to try and isolate the issue and see if its reproducible. I created a new object made up of 3 planes, and assigned them to vertex groups 1, 2, and 3 respectively. Then I added three identical solidify modifiers to the object(default settings except for 0.5m thickness and +1 offset), each linked to a separate vertex group. Lo and behold, only the first mod in the stack(didn't matter if it was for 1, 2, or 3) would function properly and the rest bugged out.


Even stranger, depending on if "fill" or "only rim" were ticked on the first modifier, the second modifier would react differently

("only rim" is ticked)

(both unticked)
Is this a bug with blender or am I missing something here?

Since I cannot really see a coherent behaviour I would assume this is a bug and should be reported. Otherwise I cannot really see how this could be intended behaviour.

The way I understand it, if you use solidify multiple times, you solidify multiple times and vertex group just controls the thickness. I don't think this is a bug, it's just that in this case you should not use solidify multiple times, you should use the weight of the vertex group if you want different thickness. I believe the intended functionality of 2 solidify modifiers is to solidify twice so there is no bug here, just the functionality is misunderstood.

The documentation is clear on this: "The weights of the selected vertex group are multiplied onto the Thickness, so vertices with lower weights will be less thick. The vertices which are not part of the vertex group will be used as if their weight was zero." Vertex group is not supposed to define what geometry is affected by solidify, just its thickness.

Although I guess this is a bug, here is another way to get what you want, at least if all modifier settings should be the same and you only want the thickness to be varying (just in case you did not know about it):
On the Solidify modifier below the Vertex Group selection there is a Factor value. This tells the modifier to what percentage the modifier should affect the mesh parts which are not in the group. Apart from that, if you want parts to not have the full thickness set in the modifier, you do not have to give them a weight of 1, you can assign them a lower weight in the vertex group.
Take the following example: I have three planes just like you, the first one on the left is assigned to a vertex group with a Weight of 1, the second plane in the middle is not assigned to the group (i.e. it has a Weight of 0), the third on the right is assigned to the group with a Weight of 0.6, and the modifier should add a Thickness of 1 m, the Factor is 0:

Now you can also give thickness to the plane which is not assigned to the group with the Factor, the tool tip if you hover your mouse over it says it is the "Thickness factor to use for zero vertex group influence" (which I shortened a bit to zero groups in the image below). But notice how this also influences the plane on the right which has a bit of weight instead of zero influence:

The reason for this is, with a vertex group the modifier calculates the specific thickness $t$ of a face from the given modifier Thickness $T$, the face vertices' weight $w$ and the Factor $f$ by this formula:
$$\begin{align}t&=T(w+f(1-w))
\\&=T(w+f-fw)
\\&=Tw+Tf-Tfw\end{align}$$
If you do not use the Factor so that $f$ = 0, this formula gets shortened to the resulting thickness being only dependent on the weight, what I show in the first image:
$$t=T\cdot w$$
Now if I use a Factor > 0, the full formula comes into play. With $T$ being 1 m and a factor $f$ of 0.3, for the left plane with a vertex weight $w$ of 1 this results in:
$$\begin{align}t&=\text{1 m}\cdot(1+0.3\cdot(1-1))
\\&=\text{1 m}\cdot(1+0)
\\&=\text{1 m}\end{align}$$
The middle plane with all vertices having a weight $w$ of 0 it gets you:
$$\begin{align}t&=\text{1 m}\cdot(0+0.3\cdot(1-0))
\\&=\text{1 m}\cdot(0+0.3)
\\&=\text{0.3 m}\end{align}$$
And finally the "mixed bag" to the right, the plane with vertex weights $w$ = 0.6:
$$\begin{align}t&=\text{1 m}\cdot(0.6+0.3\cdot(1-0.6))
\\&=\text{1 m}\cdot(0.6+0.3\cdot0.4))
\\&=\text{1 m}\cdot(0.6+0.12)
\\&=\text{0.72 m}\end{align}$$
So to sum it all up, if you simply want two different thicknesses on a mesh, you can just use the Vertex Group option where all vertices either be in the group with a weight of 1 and the others have a weight of 0 (i.e. are not in the group), then the group vertices get the full thickness and the others get a percentage of the thickness which you can set with the Factor.
If you want more than two different thicknesses, you can control this by different weights of the vertices in the group. Of course you can additionally use the Factor in this case as well, just be aware that this will have an additional effect to the weighted vertices as well, like shown above.
As you can see, a single Solidify modifier can not only be used to give a single, constant thickness throughout the mesh. Take the following example: the base mesh are just four adjacent flat faces. I show them in Weight Paint mode so that you can see how the vertices have different weights on them:

Without the Vertex Group selection they would all get the same constant thickness overall. But using the vertex group which holds the weight information, you get this result:

So what you can basically do on a plane with a higher resolution is create some kind of displacement with weight painting, only that it's not displacing a plane, but extruding it with the Solidify modifier:

If you want to make sure that there is no area which has a thickness of 0 to avoid non-manifold geometry, just give the Factor a value slightly above 0:

